# How to pass c# variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, frontend

I have variable containing some text.Basically I am trying to do toggle(hide/show) in html using c#.I want to pass this variable to javascript function that is performing hide and show .

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string res = null;
            string toggle = null;
            res += "<div style=\"display: none;\">This is the content that is dynamically being collapsed.</div>";
            toggle += "<html><head>";
            toggle += "<script type=\"text/javascript\"></script><script> function toggle2(showDetails) {var ele =document.getElementById(showDetails);if(ele.style.display == \"block\") {ele.style.display = \"none\";}else {ele.style.display = \"block\";}}</script>";
            toggle += "</head>";
            toggle += "<body>";
            toggle += "<a href=\"javascript:toggle2('"+res+"')\">collapse</a>";
            toggle += "</body>";
            toggle += "</html>";

            FileStream log = new FileStream(@"E:\report2.html", FileMode.Create);
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(log, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                w.WriteLine(toggle);
            }
        }
```

On clicking collapse,it should display the content of variable res.Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you aren't trying to pass a *variable* to a JavaScript function, you are trying to write the value of the variable into the function signature.  Second of all, you never actually insert the `div` into the DOM anywhere, and it doesn't have an `id`, so `getElementById` won't ever return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You've got multiple issues:

- The "quotes" inside your string are messing with the href="quotes"
- Your JavaScript function is incorrect
- The general approach is unusual/ very error-prone
- Nitpicking: Don't use += and `null`

### First, those quotes

Take a look at your file report2.html in your favourite text editor and you'll probably see this:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle2('<div style="display: none;">This is the content that is dynamically being collapsed.</div>')">
```

StackOverflow's code colouring helps here - notice that `display:none;` is black. This is because it's essentially seeing just `href="javascript:toggle2('<div style="`

A simple fix is to double-escape those quotes in your `res` string:

```
<div style=\\\"display: none;\\\">This is the content..
```

..but *yikes*. This kind of thing is really not recommended *unless you have to*!

### Second, the function

I (and many others!) really dislike JavaScript inside a string like this - it **promotes bad code formatting**, for starters. Let's undo that and make it pretty:

```
function toggle2(showDetails) {

    var ele =document.getElementById(showDetails);
    
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

That's better! So, firstly, `showDetails` is not an ID of an element - it's a full string of content. Pass an ID instead:

```
function toggle2(elementID) {

    var ele =document.getElementById(elementID);
    
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

This way you can instead use, e.g:

```
toggle+="<div id='collapsibleDiv'>"+res+"</div>";
toggle+="<div onmousedown=\"toggle2('collapsibleDiv');\">Click me!</div>";
```

instead. A bonus here is that it doesn't need to deal with those quotes in res.

### Null and +=

Right at the start you've got this:

```
string res=null;
res+="...";
```

It's safer to just use `string res="..";` instead as adding a null to anything is bad practice. Some programming languages will straight crash on you.

Comment: My actual need is to pass string res as an argument to javascript function and to perform hide/show, so is it possible?

Comment: @Mahek You can't hide/show just a string - you must have an element that you can reference (typically by id - I used the ID `collapsibleDiv` in the answer). Make it hidden by default if you need to with `"<div id='collapsibleDiv' style='display:none;'>"+res+"</div>"`.